# There exists a unique stable limit cycle around $(0,0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system
$$
x'=\mu x-y-x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \, y'=x+\mu y-y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
I am working on that show that (1) as $\mu>0$, there exists a unique stable limit cycle around $(0,0)$ (2) as $\mu\le 0$, there is no limit cycle around $(0,0)$. And draw the phase portraits for these two cases. Also, draw the bifurcation diagram.

---

My proof: note that the only critical point is $(0,0)$ and $$Df(0,\mu) =\begin{pmatrix}
\mu & -1 \\
1 & \mu 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $(0,0)$ is stable if $\mu<0$ and $(0,0)$ is unstable if $\mu>0$.

For $\mu=0$, consider the polar coordinate:
$$
r'=r(\mu-r), \theta'=1
$$

So $\mu=0$, $(0,0)$ is a stable focus.

For $\mu>0$, there is a limit cycle $(\mu \cos t, \mu \sin t)$. [** Question: But how to say that is unique?**]

Since as $\mu<0$, $(0,0)$ is unstable, then there is no limit cycle.

---

The phase portraits:

[image]

The bifurcation diagram: The red line is $r=\mu$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can study everything is polar coordinate, as the system in that case is reduced to 1-d.
You have

$$
\dot{r} = r(m-r) =: f_\mu(r)
$$

with fixed points $r=0$ and $r= \mu$.
The stability is controlled by by

$$
f'_\mu(r):=\frac{d}{dr}f_\mu(r) =\mu - 2r
$$.
Going by cases:

- $\mu < 0$ : The only acceptable fixed point is $r=0$ (since $r$ must be
  positive). We see it is stable cause

$$
 f'_\mu(0) =  \mu <0
 $$

So there is no limit cycle, and the origin attracts all trajectories.

- $\mu > 0$: Now both fixed points are acceptable and we see

$$
 f'_\mu(r=0) =  \mu >0
 $$
Meaning that $r=0$ is repelling. And

$$
 f'_\mu(r=\mu) =  -\mu < 0
 $$
Which means that $r=\mu$ is repelling.
This proves the uniqueness of the limit cycle (and actually, also its existence), as all the trajectories on the plane are attracted to it (both from the 'inside' and from the 'outside' the closed orbit). A stable periodic orbit does not necessarily have this property. Thus, proving that 0 is unstable is not enough.

- $\mu = 0$: This is tricky as if you use the formulas from before you would get $f'(\mu)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$. But it is wrong to proceed in this way. First we notice that the equation for $\mu=0$ reads:
  $$
   f_\mu(r) = -r^2
  $$
  Making the only equilibrium ($r=0$) attracting ($f'_\mu(0)=-r <0$ for all $r>0$).

---

It might be nice to know that $f(r) = x(\mu-x)$ is the famous [logistic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Logistic_differential_equation), that can be solved analytically.

Comment: Thanks. So my solution looks good? How about the diagram?

Comment: Seems good, but I don't know what that red line stands for.

Also, did you check whether the system is rotating clockwise or not?

Comment: Oh, the red line is $r=\mu$. How to check that?

Comment: Just pick one point of the original system, e.g., (1,0),  and see whether the derivative points up or down.

Comment: Sorrry, the derivative of which function?

Comment: Hi, can you please take a look at this question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4818908/identity-all-bifurcation-that-occur-in-the-system-for-mu-and-bifurcation-diag? Thank you!

Comment: the original one. just compute f(1,0) and see whether it points up or down.

Comment: I got $Df(0,\mu)$ and wrote it in the question. Do you mean $Df(1,0)$? But that would be a matrix, right?

Comment: no i mean computing f(1,0). We can see that f(x = 0, y = 1) is given by

$$
x' = -1
$$
(pointing left)
and 

$$
y' = \mu -1 
$$

(pointing down for $\mu <1$).
So the spiral is clockwise as you have drawn it for $\mu <0$ but I think that the spiral inside the limit circle is counter-clockwise (I'm not sure, please double check).

Comment: Well, do you mean counter-clockwise as $\mu<0$? It seems that I draw counter-clockwise...

Comment: I think is clockwise as f(0,1) Points down and left, sorry. But really just compute it yourself to double check, I might have made mistakes.

Comment: But what I draw is counter-clockwise for $\mu<0$...

Comment: You are probably right, I was on my phone and I got confused. Anyway you can use this

https://www.geogebra.org/m/utcMvuUy

to plot the system and see how it varies with mu